# Assets Android

Tags: android, java, webview

**Доброго времени суток!**

Столкнулся с неожиданной для себя проблемой при попытке загрузить HTML файл из стандартного каталога assets/ ( в сборке ) в компонент WebView. Как ни странно в последних версиях Android`a все работает без проблем, но в версиях Android 2.3.3 и ниже загрузка не происходит! Старые версии андройда не поддерживают каталог Assets? Почему загрузка DOM-модели не происходит из HTML файла в WebView? Вот, как происходит загрузка:

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: больше кода покажите. и кавычку забыли.  
в 2.3.3 все работает.

Comment: Тут ведь дело в том, что проблема явно не в коде. Если заменить ссылку на другую, ту, что ведет на глобальный ресурс, опять же, все будет работать. Дело здесь именно в assets/. Вы можете это сами проверить на эмуляторе с древней версией андройда.

Comment: Замучил несколько эмулей результат однозначный: без проблем грузится из asset даже на v1.1
Может сам эмуль у Вас чудит - пересоздавать не пробовали?

Comment: Как оказалось, проблема не в эмуляторах и не в assets`ах. Все дело в самом HTML файле...В нем был вредоносный JS, скрывающий содержимое страницы. Вот так.

Answer (score 2):

```
WebView wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.splashWebView);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
  {  
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
  }  
}); 
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html_no_copy/demo_welcome.html");
```